# Specrun continue on error of a step

Tags: specflow

Is there a way to continue the execution of a scenario with steps, and if an error occurred for a step just fail that step and continue with the next set of steps?   I'm using specrun to run my tests within visual studio.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without you manually handling the exceptions. https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/447

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: I have 10 smoke test scenarios, and when ran can take up to 20 mins. Ideally we would like our tests to run under 10 mins. Each test scenario is independent of each, and they each log into the app, perform the test, and then log out. Since we do not control the test data. We have to start from an original state of the application.   Is there a way to call scenarios from a scenario? I'm just trying to shorten our test run time and the number of times we are having open browser, login, and close browser for each scenario. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Is there some sort of configuration I can use to continue on error of a step.  If I combine my scenarios to create one big scenario which may test multiple functionality, then I would just want to fail steps within my scenario but continue to the entire workflow